# net_cls and ns subsystems not available in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, lxc, cgroup

I'm playing around with cgroups and I noticed when I try to list all available subsystems that the network ones are not available ? Running the following command should list ALL available subsystems - including the ones which are not attached to any hierarchy.
Am I missing something ?

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ lssubsys -a 
devices
freezer
blkio
perf_event
cpuset,cpu,cpuacct,memory
```

I'm running the following Kernel:

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ uname -a
Linux precise64 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And using the latest lxc build - although I know that shouldn't have any effect on this:

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ dpkg -l|grep lxc
ii  liblxc0                         1.0.0~alpha2+master~20131025-2342-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 Linux Containers userspace tools (library)
ii  lxc                             1.0.0~alpha2+master~20131025-2342-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 Linux Containers userspace tools
ii  lxc-templates                   1.0.0~alpha2+master~20131025-2342-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 Linux Containers userspace tools (templates)
ii  python3-lxc                     1.0.0~alpha2+master~20131025-2342-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 Linux Containers userspace tools (Python 3.x bindings)
vagrant@precise64:~$
```

And the following cgroup-bin package;

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ dpkg -l|grep cgroup-bin
iF  cgroup-bin                      0.37.1-1ubuntu10.1                                       Tools to control and monitor control groups
vagrant@precise64:~$
```